# UPDATE Query in MS Access using SQL in VBA with declared strings

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

been a while since I've posted so please forgive any formatting issues. Looking to update a table field with a value from another record in the same field in the same table.

I've declared two strings, and the strDeal string is coming back with the correct values when debugging.  However when I introduce the string into the sql statement I can't the query to update the field.  I'm not sure exactly what isn't working correctly, so any help would be appreciated.

The basics are I'm trying to update the `Case_Qty` field with a value from the same field in the same table based on the returned value from a subquery.  Thanks!

```
Dim strDeal As String
Dim strSQL As String

strDeal = DMax("[Deal_No]", "[tblStructuresNoDAworking]", "[Structure_Name] = Forms!frmStructNoDASetup!Structure_Name AND [FG_Ind] = 0 AND [Deal_No] < Forms!frmStructNoDASetup!Deal_No")

strSQL = "UPDATE tblStructuresNoDAworking SET tblStructuresNoDAworking.Case_Qty = (SELECT [Case_Qty] FROM tblStructuresNoDAworking WHERE [Structure_Name] = '" & Me.Structure_Name.Value & "' AND [Deal_No] = '" & strDeal & "') WHERE [Structure_Name] = '" & Me.Structure_Name.Value & "' AND [Deal_No] = '" & Me.Deal_No.Value & "'"

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
```

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271) -- 1) add the content of `strSQL` to your question, 2) add the error message you get when running that SQL in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this where you concatenate the values from the form:

```vb
Dim strDeal As String
Dim strSQL  As String

strDeal = DMax("[Deal_No]", "[tblStructuresNoDAworking]", "[Structure_Name] = '" & Forms!frmStructNoDASetup!Structure_Name & "' AND [FG_Ind] = 0 AND [Deal_No] < '" & Forms!frmStructNoDASetup!Deal_No & "'")
strSQL = "UPDATE tblStructuresNoDAworking " & _
    "SET tblStructuresNoDAworking.Case_Qty = " & _ 
    "    (SELECT [Case_Qty] " & _
    "    FROM tblStructuresNoDAworking " & _
    "    WHERE [Structure_Name] = '" & Me.Structure_Name.Value & "' AND [Deal_No] = '" & strDeal & "') " & _
    "WHERE [Structure_Name] = '" & Me.Structure_Name.Value & "' AND [Deal_No] = '" & Me.Deal_No.Value & "'"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

For numeric Deal:

```vb
Dim Deal    As Long
Dim strSQL  As String

Deal = DMax("[Deal_No]", "[tblStructuresNoDAworking]", "[Structure_Name] = '" & Forms!frmStructNoDASetup!Structure_Name & "' AND [FG_Ind] = 0 AND [Deal_No] < '" & Forms!frmStructNoDASetup!Deal_No & "'")
strSQL = "UPDATE tblStructuresNoDAworking " & _
    "SET tblStructuresNoDAworking.Case_Qty = " & _ 
    "    (SELECT [Case_Qty] " & _
    "    FROM tblStructuresNoDAworking " & _
    "    WHERE [Structure_Name] = '" & Me.Structure_Name.Value & "' AND [Deal_No] = " & Deal & ") " & _
    "WHERE [Structure_Name] = '" & Me.Structure_Name.Value & "' AND [Deal_No] = " & Me.Deal_No.Value & ""

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gustav.  Unfortunately this still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Then follow the link provided by @Andre.

Comment: @ Gustav Will do - I should have also mentioned that the value returned by strDeal needs to be numeric.  Not sure if that is playing in here.

Comment: It may, but you have declared it as a string ...

Comment: This is where I'm unclear - do I need to declare it as an integer?  The condition it's trying to fulfill in the sql statement is looking at an integer field.

Comment: Yes, no quotes in the SQL. See extended answer, please.